# Div elements are distorted on float: right;

Tags: html, css

I want this image and text to float right and have some distance around them, but they stretch out the default resolution and float exceedingly over on  *float: right;*.

```css
#pageMain {
  margin: 100px;
}

#aboutGame {
  float: right;
  width: 420px;
  padding: 10px;
}

#aboutGame span {
  width: ;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

#aboutGame img {
  border: 3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<section id="pageMain">
  <div id="aboutGame">
    <span>
   As if awakening from a deep sleep, you find yourself in a strange, contradictory world of ancient ruins and advanced technology. Tasked by your creator with solving a series of increasingly complex puzzles, you must decide whether to have faith, or to ask the difficult questions: Who are you? What is your purpose and what are you going to do about it? </span>
    <img src="http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steam/apps/257510/ss_ded5cd1a34df5b4d9015f71caf35db247b2579c4.1920x1080.jpg?t=1498680189" height="500px" width="800px" />
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: So are you wanting the text to wrap around the image or for it to be floated right along with the image?

Comment: I assume the image's distortion is caused by its `width` and `height` attributes not reflecting its original proportions. E.g. 800/500 != 1920/1080.

Comment: What do you mean by "stretch out the default resolution and float exceedingly over"?  Float doesn't affect image resolution and can't stretch an image.   If your'e trying to get the text to wrap around the image, put the image tag before the text, not after it (and put the float on the image, not the container.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
#pageMain {
  margin: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#aboutGame {
  float: right;
  width: 420px;
  padding: 10px;
}

#aboutGame span {
  width: ;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

#aboutGame img {
  border: 3px solid #000;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  margin: 20px 0;
}
```

```html
<section id="pageMain">
  <div id="aboutGame">
    <span>
   As if awakening from a deep sleep, you find yourself in a strange, contradictory world of ancient ruins and advanced technology. Tasked by your creator with solving a series of increasingly complex puzzles, you must decide whether to have faith, or to ask the difficult questions: Who are you? What is your purpose and what are you going to do about it? </span>
    <img src="http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steam/apps/257510/ss_ded5cd1a34df5b4d9015f71caf35db247b2579c4.1920x1080.jpg?t=1498680189" height="500px" width="800px" />
  </div>
</section>
```

I think this is what you wanted to do, so i added some styling to image tag and overflow:hidden to parent #pageMain div. because its children elements are floated and it was having clearing issue.

Comment: i think you should remove `overflow:hidden` as its cutting out the portion of the data on screen , its better if you resize them inside div-containers and make it responsive (it would have been better and solve all issue automatically)

Answer (score 0):

Your Question is not very clear, But let me know if this works for you

```css
#pageMain {
  margin: 100px;
}

#aboutGame {
  float: right;
  width: 420px;
  padding: 10px;
}

#aboutGame span {
  width: 100%;
  text-align:right;
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

#aboutGame img {
  border: 3px solid black;
  width:100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<section id="pageMain">
  <div id="aboutGame">
    <span>
    As if awakening from a deep sleep, you find yourself in a strange, contradictory world of ancient ruins and advanced technology. Tasked by your creator with solving a series of increasingly complex puzzles, you must decide whether to have faith or to ask the difficult questions: Who are you? What is your purpose and what are you going to do about it? </span>
    <img src="http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steam/apps/257510/ss_ded5cd1a34df5b4d9015f71caf35db247b2579c4.1920x1080.jpg?t=1498680189" />
  </div>
</section>
```

**Changes I made to your code:**

**1.** Removed the width and height attribute from image tag as suggested by **showdev** as it was making the image larger than the container itself.

**2.**

```
#aboutGame span {
    width: 100%; //Define width the span takes
    text-align:right; //Aligns the text to right, you can use left/center/justify according to your need
    display: block; //Displays elements as a block 
    margin-bottom: 50px; // Gives spacing between image and text
  }

  #aboutGame img {
    height: auto; // Takes the height according to the width
  }
```

Comment: A little explanation would be helpful. What was the problem and how does your code solve it?

Comment: he just used `height :auto;`  in css, which makes the image responsive (responsive means the element resize with respect to screen size) @pra, @show